# "Attachment does not contain a definition for CopyTo"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to save a file in StorageBlob, basically when I get an email with an attachment is when I do this

```
foreach (var docUploaded in files)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    docUploaded.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
```

This is the line where I got the error `docUploaded.CopyTo(ms);`
I have used it but for IFormFile files but for message.Attachments for Outlook I cannot and also tried to convert it from the message.attachment into IFormFile but not success.
I got this message "Attachment does not contain a definition for CopyTo" does anyone know a different way to do it, there's no much info about it, greetings.

Comment: `docUploaded.ContentStream.CopyTo(ms);`

Comment: I cannot use ContentStream just ContentType this is my files variable                              
var files = message.Attachments;

Comment: COuld you please provide the code how you get Attachments?

Comment: @JimXu I have a Microsoft Graph Subscription page = await graphClient.Users["myemail"].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Delta().Request().Header("Prefer", "odata.maxpagesize=2").Select("Subject, UniqueBody, From").Expand("attachments").GetAsync();

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Comment: singhh-msft The info it's kind of new for me jaja and not easy to understand, i'll be looking the info in case that that helps I will let you know

Comment: Sure, it is very simple. :) Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone i found out a way
var files = message.Attachments.CurrentPage.ToList();

```
                            foreach (var docUploaded in files)
                            {
                                var fileAttachment = docUploaded as Microsoft.Graph.FileAttachment;
                                var inputAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(fileAttachment.ContentBytes);
                                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(inputAsString));
}
```

This is the way that solved my issue, now it is saving in the blobStorage(there's a method where i sent ms and some information). So basically  converted it :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to write this functionality's code as it is done Out of box using Logic Apps.

Check out [Tutorial: Automate tasks to process emails by using Azure Logic Apps, Azure Functions, and Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow) for detailed steps on how to do it. This tutorial shows how you can build a logic app that handles incoming emails and any attachments. This logic app analyzes the email content, saves the content to Azure storage, and sends notifications for reviewing that content.